# Inference from text data without label or Target

Tags: nlp, clustering, text-mining

I have a use case where I have text data entered by an approver while approving some loans.

I have to make some inferences as to what could be the reasons for approval using NLP. How should I go about it?

It's a Non-English language. Can Clustering of text help?? Is it possible to cluster TEXT OF non-English language using python libraries?

Comment: Unsupervised text learning could start with topic modeling: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/79360_850b2a69980c4488b1db95987a24867a.html

Comment: So you have the text of the evaluation where I assume the approver explains the reason, right? Are you trying to summarize the reason given by the approver? Because that's completely different from clustering.

Comment: @Erwan, yes..I want to summarize

Comment: @sayan_sen then you should look at [text summarization techniques](https://nlpprogress.com/english/summarization.html), there are lots of options. clustering won't give you the same thing at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to cluster TEXT OF non English language using python libraries?**

Sure! classic approaches based on Bag-of-Words are language independent. For modern approaches based on DNNs, mostly pre-trained models, you just need to find a model in your language or train one model from scratch (for this you need lots of text in that language). For example in case of using AWS infrastructure, check [Object2Vec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/object2vec-howitworks.html) algorithm.

**Can Clustering of text help?**

Can help. For instance for an initial labeling you can cluster data into similar texts and labels each according to overal concept. More sophisticated solution (easily implemented in python) is topic modeling e.g. [LDA](https://towardsdatascience.com/end-to-end-topic-modeling-in-python-latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda-35ce4ed6b3e0) algorithm.

More sophisticated solution is, again, pre-trained models like [S-BERT](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/applications/clustering.py).

In this direction, I also recommend having an analysis on [keywords](https://monkeylearn.com/keyword-extraction/) for algorithms like [RAKE](https://thinkinfi.com/automatic-keyword-extraction-using-rake-in-python/) or [YAKE](https://github.com/LIAAD/yake).

Hope it helps!